# PyQt5 embedding a 3D scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

Im trying to use 3D plot with PyQt5 and I cant get the rotation of the plot working.
Ive got matplotlib toolbar half working, it can save and resize the plot.
Zoom and move is not working although its working with 2d plot, not sure if scatter plot allows to zoom or move. What I need is the rotation working.

The code so far:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QMainWindow, QApplication, QSizePolicy, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Qt5Agg")

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d, Axes3D



class MyMplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    # Ultimately, this is a QWidget (as well as a FigureCanvasAgg, etc.).
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.fig = fig
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
        # self.fig = plt.figure()
        # self.axes = Axes3D(self.fig)

        self.compute_initial_figure()
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)
        self.setParent(parent)

        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,
                                   QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                                   QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)

    def compute_initial_figure(self):
        pass


class MyStaticMplCanvas(MyMplCanvas):
    # Simple canvas with a sine plot.
    def compute_initial_figure(self):
        # t = arange(0.0, 3.0, 0.01)
        # s = sin(2 * pi * t)
        # self.axes.plot(t, s)
        xs = [1, 2]
        ys = [1, 2]
        zs = [1, 2]

        self.axes.scatter(xs, ys, zs, c='b')

        self.axes.mouse_init()


class PlotDialog(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.plot_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.plot_canvas = MyStaticMplCanvas(self, width=5, height=4, dpi=100)

        self.navi_toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.plot_canvas, self)
        self.plot_layout.addWidget(self.plot_canvas)  # the matplotlib canvas
        self.plot_layout.addWidget(self.navi_toolbar)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = PlotDialog()
    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to initialize the mouse after updating the geometry, in your case you are doing them before causing the failure.

```
# ...
FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,
                           QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                           QSizePolicy.Expanding)
FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)
self.axes.mouse_init()
# ...
```